# Advice in member/asp.net MVC Approving users before they are being created in "User" table and getting acces to platform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Dear every good fellows in this forum

Currently I am creating a site where there shalld be a sign up page - not to created every user but only to approve them.

I havent seen any samples on "disable" user in MVC identity but now from the previus "asp.net" membership that there was a possibiliy to make a "approve" user etc.

I am thinking of making a signup page that has now relation to the users in and then after make a function that transfer data to te user table.

Is this the right approach?

If any information is need please let me know.

Happy coding

Best regards
Casper KVolle.

Comment: I would say you should still insert them into the users table to properly reserve their slot (unique email/username). There should be an `EmailConfirmed` field you could utilise so they can't log in until that is `true`. You could then have a section on your site to vet the new users and approve. Alternatively, extend the `ApplicationUser` model to have a new `approved` field(s) then block off the login to not let them in until approval has been completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you set up roles, and limit and grant functionality by roles. You can assign roles in code or by manually manipulating the database. Roles are part of aspnet identity and the database tables that support it.

You can apply the authorize with role parameters as such on your controller and actions

```
[Authorize(Roles="Client, Adminstrator")]
public ActionResult ChangePrice(int ProductID, int price)
{
return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) will try to making a mix of the options that you menrrion here:-)